# How do I brew an X potion?

Tags: candy-box-2

The instructions are:

> The X potion is a legend. It is said
>  that whoever manage to brew it and drink
>  it would travel to a place where no one 
>  have been before.
>
>    I don't know if this potion is just a 
>  legend or not, but I will write in this 
>  book everything I know about it.
>
>    The X potion is mentioned in many old 
>  legends and alchemy books. Here's a
>  summary of the informations which may
>  help you to brew it. Good luck!
>
>   - It is said that 5 steps are necessary
>  to brew the X potion.
>
>   - It is said that no lollipops are
>  required, except for one of the steps.
>
>   - It is said that, unlike for other
>  potions, you can't brew multiple X
>  potions at once.
>  
>  quoted when it comes to the X potion :
>  
>             On the first day,
>   it gave birth to the very first Sweet. 
>          But it was cold outside.
>
>             On the second day,
>         it gave the Sweet a father.
>          But it was cold outside.
>
>             On the third day,
>         it gave the Sweet a brother.
>          But it was cold outside.
>
>             On the fourth day,
>         it gave the Sweet a friend.
>          But it was cold outside.
>
>             On the fifth day,
>         it gave the Sweet a lover,
>      and it may sound simple or silly,
>        but now the Sweet was happy,
>          and it was hot outside.

Comment: holy wall of spoiler!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually found this extremely easy; it’s rather easy if you think about it. It says no lollipops are required except once, so you’d expect four candies one lollipop.

1. The first one is a candy as it says "**the first day was cold**" so put 1 candy in the cauldron and boil it quickly then stop once it reaches cold.
2. Second is "**gave the sweet a father**", repeat the step.
3. Then "**gave the sweet a brother**" repeat again.
4. And again for "**a friend**".
5. Then on the “5th day” (5th step) "**gave the sweet a "lover"**". You’d assume it’s different and, so this is the step where the lollipop comes in.
6. It says "**and it was hot outside**" so boil until it says “Boiling... very hot”.
7. Bottle it and you’ll get your X potion.

> The X potion takes you to kill "yourself"

Comment: The answer is almost correct - you have to boil to cold every time a candy is added. As the sentences end on "but it was cold outside"

Comment: In my experience, I had to heat to boiling on the last day, are we sure it's only to hot?

Comment: I was just able to brew it, by bottling almost the exact moment it said hot.

Comment: Extremely easy? I think that's the epitoam of hyperbowl.